# Преобразование или удаление из 16-ричной системы в текст

Tags: python, строки, кодировка

ЯП: python
Имеется строка "\xe3\x80\x90\xe4\xba\x88\xe7\xb4\x84\xe7\x89\xb9\xe5\x85\xb8\xe4\xbb\x98\xe3\x81\x8d\xe3\x80\x91ELDEN RING SHADOW OF THE ERDTREE \xe3\x83\x97\xe3\x83\xac\xe3\x83\x9f\xe3\x82\xa2\xe3\x83\xa0\xe3\x83\x90\xe3\x83\xb3\xe3\x83\x89\xe3\x83\xab"
Не могу понять как преобразовать символы в текст или просто удалить все кроме обычного текста, пробовал преобразовать строку в байты и потом обратно, выводит тоже самое

Answer (score 0):

```
s=b"\xe3\x80\x90\xe4\xba\x88\xe7\xb4\x84\xe7\x89\xb9\xe5\x85\xb8\xe4\xbb\x98\xe3\x81\x8d\xe3\x80\x91ELDEN RING SHADOW OF THE ERDTREE \xe3\x83\x97\xe3\x83\xac\xe3\x83\x9f\xe3\x82\xa2\xe3\x83\xa0\xe3\x83\x90\xe3\x83\xb3\xe3\x83\x89\xe3\x83\xab"
print(s.decode('utf-8'))
```

##### Перевожу с помощью переводчика:

> 【予約特典付き】ELDEN RING SHADOW OF THE ERDTREE プレミアムバンドル
>
> [С бонусом за предзаказ] Премиум-набор ELden RING SHADOW OF THE
> ERDTREE

Comment: Ошибка: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-7: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: @dozzier у меня нет ошибки и нет encode.

Comment: Ну вот я просто скопироват твой код и вставил, выдал это, не могу понять с чем связанно, какая версия python у вас?